# css font family : Why some font doesn't render on mobile

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

Does any one know why some of my font families won't render on some mobile devices?  Here's a page that demonstrates the fonts:

http://jl.evermight.com/font/

The fonts render properly on desktop chrome browser, ipad and iphone.
But when i view that page on my galaxy note, the Have A Nice Day font renders as something that looks like arial.  On my friends nexus 4, Have a nice day works fine, but the universe condense renders as something that looks like arial.

Does anyone know why?

I've attached screenshot of what the fonts should look like[image]

**Additional notes**
some people claim Have a nice day is not working in Firefox or IE10.  For me, the font works on Firefox.  I don't have IE10, so unable to verify.

How do I make this font work on my android?

**Additional Notes**
I had a typing mistake in my link path to my css files.  I've corrected it now.  But the problem still appears in my droid browser.

Comment: doesn't render on Firefox either. Might have to do with the browser's supported font formats.

Comment: BTW it works fine on my galaxy note's Chrome browser. Do you have problems with the native android browser or which browser?

Comment: that's correct, im using the native droid browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed.  Apparently there was a bug on myfonts.com that corrupted my font files.  I contacted myfonts.com and they corrected the issue right away.  Then re-sent me the font files.  Now everything works perfectly.

The guys at myfonts.com are amazing.  Very good customer + tech support services.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried out the link on my phone - **HTC 8s**, everything seemed to work fine. Below is the screenshot for the same.

**ON HTC 8S**

[image]

**ON IE 10**

[image]

Comment: Hi Yasser, actually in your image, the last two fonts are not working properly.  Compare your HAVEANICEDAY(s) with the one from my question.  You're experience the same problem as my galaxy note.

Comment: but then the same two fonts dont work on IE 10 either, so still not a mobile related problem, its a browser problem. (Have added screenshots from IE)

Comment: Firefox and IE (and native droid) don't support those fonts for some reason, I believe that's OP's question.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - if that is the case, is there a way to make it work in these browsers?

Comment: Oh weird, I've tested on Firefox 18, 19 and 22a and it didn't work on these. Thought about re-converting the woff and ttf files, though that's most likely not the issue. I also have font files that do not work in certain browsers.

Comment: I just corrected a url typing mistake that may be causing the issues with firefox and IE10.   So try again in FF and IE.  However, android browser remains to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it's a downloading issue. The fonts listed in your declaration should work across most browsers (just make sure you're not in Opera Mini, it doesn't really support much of anything).

Additionally, Have a Nice Day is loaded through `@font-face` declarations in the CSS file, but the others appear to be loaded from the JavaScript, which might be part of the issue. Droid Sans is on Android phones by default, so they're likely just pulling them locally, which is why they work across the board on Android. From there, it might be a difference of JavaScript support (if Universe doesn't work, JS isn't turned on, for example).

Another thing that might help is opening up developer tools in a desktop browser that isn't working (in the case of Firefox, you'll want to pick up the Firebug extension). Check the "Net" or "Network" tab and see if your font files are getting downloaded.

If that still doesn't work, try playing around with the order of the font files in the declaration. I've seen browsers take issue with the order.

Also, the Droid Serif fonts are available from [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), which works cross browser with little headache. It might be worth seeing if your other fonts (or something close) are there, too, and just use Google's Web Font Loader to load your fonts.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a link to how I do my @fontfaces for cross browser compatibility.

[Cross Browser Fontface](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

Comment: While this may or may not technically answer the question, you should write out a better explanation in your answer. Links are known to go dead, and so an answer dependent on a link may become useless in the future.